# Passing arguments from a button in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I want to be abble to click on a button in a Google Sheet and add +1 to a particular cell.

I have this script :

```
function AddOne(inputCell) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange(inputCell).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue() + 1);
};
```

On the button, I assigned the script

```
AddOne('C6')
```

When I click on the button, i have the error `Script function AddOne('C6') could not be found`.

Can you please help me resolve this matter ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the cell you want to add to *always* C6?

Comment: No, I want  to use several buttons, but just One script.

Answer (score 2):

**An addOne button that adds one to the current cell**

```
function addOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveCell();
  rg.setValue(rg.getValue()+1);
}
```

Just go to insert/Drawing pick a plus shape. Save it and place it on your sheet and attach the script with the three dots in the upper right hand corner. Select any cell that you want to increment and press the plus sign and it get's incremented by one.  You could make a minus one too.

Comment: I though about this solution but in fact, I would like to have one button per cell, it's easier for basic user to click on the "+"/"-" button on the cell they want to add rather than first click on the cell then on the button.